# Cypress JS custom commands not working in VUE CLI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, cypress

I'm trying to set up a custom command to add some session storage items in a project and it doesn't seem to be firing.

The command is as follows

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", "tokengoeshere");
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("username", "phoenix");
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080");
});
```

I have added the file into cypress.json

```
"supportFile": "tests/e2e/support/index.js",
```

and the index.js looks like

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import "./commands";
```

When the tests fire session storage is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where are you calling that custom command?**

You usually create custom commands in `cypress/support/commands.js` file and that makes those commands available under `cy.`

So paste this to your `cypress/support/commands.js`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", "tokengoeshere");
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("username", "phoenix");
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080");
});
```

and then call it with `cy.login()` from any test file. Those are usually in `cypress/integration` folder. For example in your case a file `cypress/integration/myTestsWithCustomCommand.js`:

```js
describe("My tests using custom commands", () => {

  it("1st test using custom command", () => {
    cy.login();
    // rest of your code test
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok ill add it to the top of the file, That makes sense

Comment: Yeah it did perfectly, had to do some playing around with what I was loading in but yes fantastic